# To know which package brought particular so library

Tags: 16.04, package-management, aptitude

I have `/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6` library on my Ubuntu system. I would like to know which package brought it there. How to know that?

Comment: `libstdc++.so.6` is the C++ standard library - many applications (including those shipped by Ubuntu) depend on it.

Answer (score 7):

Please run `dpkg -S /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6`

Comment: as output I got `lib32stdc++6: /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6` . Does `lib32stdc++6` is package name?

Comment: Does it possible that `lib32stdc++6` came with another package in my system? If yes, how to know whole hierarchy then?

Comment: Sure, it is the package name. If you not sure, you can check if you have it installed by `dpkg -l | grep lib32stdc++6`

Comment: I don't remember I run command `aptitude install lib32stdc++6` is it possible that this package came with another package?

Comment: It maybe was installed as a dependency of another one.

Comment: Is it possible somehow to know which package took another one as dependency?

Comment: You can look in this file `/var/log/apt/history.log`

Answer (score 5):

Now that you know which package `/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6` came from, you can find out which packages depend on `lib32stdc++6` by running:

`sudo apt-cache rdepends lib32stdc++6`

This will give you a list of package(s) that depend/installed `lib32stdc++6`

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use the tool `apt-file` :

- Install it using :

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install apt-file
  ```
- Update it's database :

  ```
  $ sudo apt-file update
  ```
- Search for your desired file :

  ```
  $ sudo apt-file search /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6
  ```

The result should be :

```
$ apt-file search /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6
lib32stdc++6: /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6
lib32stdc++6: /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6.0.21
lib32stdc++6: /usr/share/gdb/auto-load/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6.0.21-gdb.py
lib32stdc++6-5-dbg: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6.0.21

/usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6
```

Which lead us to know that the package which installed should be `lib32stdc++6`.

Answer (score 1):

You can search it in https://packages.ubuntu.com

For your case will be [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&section=all&arch=any&keywords=lib32stdc%2B%2B6&searchon=names) link.

Comment: But how to find `libstdc++.so.6` there?

Comment: Check for the 2nd link, that link contains the search I made for you.

Comment: I see `Package lib32stdc++6` that I suppose contains many files and one of them might be `libstdc++.so.6`. But I don't see that exactly.

Comment: If you go inside the link I shared with you, you will see [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/lib32stdc++6/filelist), that's the prove of the file you are searching for.